# switch case with two spinners and audio player

Tags: android, android-spinner, audio-player

In my activity i have two spinners, one image view and two buttons.
depending on first spinner the second spinners should change. and while selecting birds in first spinner the second spinner should show parrot peacock etc. while selecting parrot in second spinner i should get the image of parrot.
till this i am getting.
but now what i want is while i press a button then i should get the voice of parrot.
 in this code when i am pressing the button    i am getting the same voice for every picture change in second spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


ImageView displayIV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
;
    Button b1;
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    Spinner friend = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner subFriend = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    displayIV=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    final ArrayList<String> friend_options = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> subfriend_options = new ArrayList<String>();

    friend_options.add("Nuz");
    friend_options.add("Dur");
    friend_options.add("Tara");
    friend_options.add("Sama");

    ArrayAdapter<String> friendAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            friend_options);
    friend.setAdapter(friendAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> subFriendAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), 
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,subfriend_options);   
    subFriend.setAdapter(subFriendAdapter);

    friend.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String friendName = 
 friend_options.get(position).toString();
            resetFriend(friendName);
```

//              subFriend.setAdapter(null);

```
        }

        private void resetFriend(String friendName) {
            subfriend_options.removeAll(subfriend_options);
            if (friendName.equals("Nuz")) {
                subfriend_options.add("Nuz_1");
                subfriend_options.add("Nuz_2");
                subfriend_options.add("Nuz_3");
                subfriend_options.add("Nuz_4");

            } else if (friendName.equals("Dur")) {
                subfriend_options.add("Dur_1");
                subfriend_options.add("Dur_2");
                subfriend_options.add("Dur_3");
                subfriend_options.add("Dur_4");

            } else if (friendName.equals("Tara")) {
                subfriend_options.add("Tara_1");
                subfriend_options.add("Tara_2");
                subfriend_options.add("Tara_3");
                subfriend_options.add("Tara_4");

            } else {
                subfriend_options.add("Sama_1");
                subfriend_options.add("Sama_2");
                subfriend_options.add("Sama_3");
                subfriend_options.add("Sama_4");

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> subFriendAdapter = new 
    ArrayAdapter<String>(               getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
  subfriend_options);
            subFriend.setAdapter(subFriendAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });

    subFriend.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
             arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            final ImageView im = 
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            String s=((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
            if(s.equals("Tara_1")){

 im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.crow));
            }

            if(s.equals("Tara_2"))

im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.india1));
            if(s.equals("Tara_3"))

im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.peacock));

            if(s.equals("Tara_4"))

im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.robin1)); 


        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });



    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            //MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
R.raw.Kalimba);  
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.abc);  
          mp.start();
         }
        });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the setOnClickListener method of your button, b1, you need to know which image has been selected on the spinner (your description is a little bit confusing so i don't have clear exactly which spinner is going to change the sound that you app has to reproduce).

Anyway, let think that the spinner is "friend_options".

In you setOnClickListener we have to know which item has been selected for the user when click on the button, right? And depending of which item was selected, we will play one specific sound.

So....

Another important poin is that you should create the variable of the mediaplayer outside of the onclickListener, like a class variable:

```
 //Class variable:
 public MediaPlayer mp;
```

In the onCreate method you should initialize the MediaPlayer component:

```
 public void onCreate()
 {
    MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,  R.raw.abc);  //Default sound, it is not 
                                                        //importat because we are going 
                                                        //to chain the value of the 
                                                        //file to reproduce in the next 
                                                        //step.
 }



 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         //Here we are going to take the item selected:
         String itemSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

         int soundToPlayId=0;

         if(itemSelected.equals("Nuz"))
         { 
            soundToPlayId = R.raw.Kalimba ; 
         }
         else if(itemSelected.equals("Dur"))
         { 
            soundToPlayId = R.raw.abc; 
         }
         // etc etc etc  --> you should put all the sound associated to all the 
         // friends

         //And now you only have to reproduce if the item was selected properly:

         if(soundToPlayId !=0)  //if the id is different to 0:
         {        
              mp = MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, soundToPlayId);  
              mp.start();
         }
     }
 });
```

Let see if it is working!!! Ask me if you have any doubt...and if the answer is correct, vote me and check as correct!!! (I need points, thanks!)

Comment: Frien is "tara" and friend_option is "Tara_1", "Tara_2" etc. til this the image is coming. what i want is when i get "Tara_1" and if i press Play button it should play a voice. and when i am selecting "Tara_2" and pressing Play it should play another voice.

Comment: Ok, that is ok...but I can't help you more. With my explication I am covering all the technical stuffs that you need for implement the functionality that you wish. It is pretty clear, now you only need to check in the proper spinner and with the proper values.

Comment: Change the spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); for subFriend.getSelectedItem().toString()  and in the structure if() that i showed you before check all the values that you need like Tara_1 or Tara_2, etc, and assign the sound that you wish for each case.

Comment: The solution to your problem is there. So check my code and modify it properly following your needed. Because the technic part is done.

Comment: And after of that, if you consider that I help you in something, please vote my solution! I need increase my rating in stackoverflow.

Comment: thnks for the help.. i will try and let u knw whethr it is working or not.